# Translating Physics: phenomena show or shows?

Tags: grammatical-number

I'm reading Russian tutorial about basic Physics and saving images for the Anki cards describe them in English, Google translator helps me.

I entered in Google translator phrase about the fact that bodies consists of small parcels.

What **phenomena show** that substances are composed of particles separated by gaps?

Why does phenomena **show**? Is phenomena a plural form?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. Phenomena - plural form. Phenomenon - is a singular form.

Comment: From the Greek.

Comment: Agreed, "a phenomenon shows" but "phenomena show"